# Mount.cifs not supported during pxe install, but working after reboot. Why?

Tags: linux, cifs, pxe-boot, preseed

I'm having trouble adding to AD on pxe-unattended install. 
The problem is on mount.cifs, a script wich gives me the following error on pxe boot install, works 2 minutes later, after the reboot.

Does anyone have an idea about what is happening here?

thanks.

```
#################
expect: /usr/bin/expect /usr/share/man/man1/expect.1.gz
########################
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
smbclient is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
mount: /bin/mount /sbin/mount.ntfs-3g /sbin/mount.fuse /sbin/mount.cifs /sbin/mount.lowntfs-3g /sbin/mount.smbfs /sbin/mount.ntfs-fuse /sbin/mount.ntfs /usr/share/man/man8/mount.8.gz /usr/share/man/man2/mount.2.gz
/bin/mount
/sbin/mount.cifs
###################
spawn **mount.cifs //xx.xx.xx.xx/software /home/sysop/fs -o username=sccmdeploy
Password: 
mount error: cifs filesystem not supported by the system
mount error(19): No such device
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)**
(END)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to see if this works..

```
modprobe cifs
```

Sounds like the module doesnt get loaded when you install?

in fact, give me an output before of

```
lsmod | grep cif
```

and after

```
lsmod | grep cif
```

*Note:* Cif might be the wrong word for the module.. :P

Comment: Sorry the delay. You got the point, the cifs module was not being loaded, only installed.